# Game Theory: how to apply it in transcriptomics?

Tags: algorithm, game-theory

Hi

I have seen [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18671248) (and also [Game Theory applied to gene expression analysis](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10288-008-0073-9), [Game Theory and Microarray Data Analysis](http://www.robertolucchetti.com/public/uploads/2013/01/TESIfinale.pdf)) authors have used **game theory** for their microarray  DEG analysis (**microarray
game**).

Is there any simple guide from you (or other online resources) that can describe how to use related formula for checking **game theory concept in the DEG analysis of RNA-seq** experiences ? (Basically is it even practical?)

Maybe there is some **software** for doing such investigation, painlessly.

**NOTE1:** For example please have a look at "Game Theory Method" in the first paper above :

> Let N 5 {1,. . .,n} be a set of genes. A microarray game is a
>   coalitional game (N, w) where the function w assigns to each coalition
>   S ( N a frequency of associations, between a condition and a
>   expression property, of genes realized in the coalition S."

Imagin  we have 150 gene up-regulated in females and 80 up-regulated in males (using de novo assembly and DESeq2 package), now how I can use game theory for mining something new or some extra connections between this collection of genes?

**NOTE2:** I have asked this question in *BIOSTARS* but no answer after 8 weeks.

Thanks